# More than one library with package name

Tags: java, android, gradle

My Gradle dependencies includes:

```
compile'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0
```

I am getting BUILD FAILED with error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources.
>   Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
>     You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
>   However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use `gradle androidDependencies` to learn where the duplicate Google Play Services is coming from. Then use `exclude` to filter the duplicates out in your Gradle dependencies, e.g.

```
compile('something.that.includes.google.play.services:1.2.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved by adding this line `android.enforceUniquePackageName = false` in `build.gradle(app)` like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
       ... ...
    }
} 
android.enforceUniquePackageName = false
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to replace these dependencies by the whole package :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

Then you could probably compile it.

OR add `android.enforceUniquePackageName = false` in your **build.gradle**.

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    android.packageBuildConfig = false
    android.enforceUniquePackageName = false

}
```

Comment: it's ok but i don't want to load all libs from play-services. because of multiDex :(

Comment: Is that all your gradle dependencies ?

Comment: So you either check manually the 18 dependencies, or add this line : `android.enforceUniquePackageName = false` in the android section.

Comment: Now the build fail is changed: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2